# Is there a better way to WaitForSeconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to c# programming, but I followed the documentation to insert a wait in my code. The problem is, it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Fixed());
}

IEnumerator Fixed()
{
    print("fixed clone");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

    Vector3 originalPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5f, 5f), Random.Range(-2, 2), 100);
    Rigidbody clone = Instantiate(original, originalPosition, transform.rotation);
    clone.velocity = rb.velocity * speed;
}
```

(This is just a snippet of the code.) In Unity, when I play the clones come rocketing out, and with each clone comes the "fixed clone" message in my console, so I know it's coming from here.

If you need the whole code to figure the problem, I can insert that as well.

Comment: You may include your actual code so we can have a look whats wrong.

Comment: You might as well add another print after the `WaitForSeconds(5)` to validate whether the function is working and really waited 5 seconds

Comment: if you still having problem , why you not try Instantiate as GameObject and then change value , may that help to understand flow and solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you simply want to spawn an object after a delay. You don't really need a Coroutine to do this. Coroutines are good for manipulating objects over a number of frames, or frame by frame.

To simply run a function after a delay try the [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) method:

```
void Start()
{
    Invoke("SpawnClone", 5.0f); //Call SpawnClone 5 seconds after start
}

void SpawnClone()
{
    print("fixed clone");

    Vector3 originalPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5f, 5f), Random.Range(-2, 2), 100);

    Rigidbody clone;
    clone = Instantiate(original, originalPosition, transform.rotation);
    clone.velocity = rb.velocity * speed;
}
```

OR Try this to trigger as Coroutine

```
private IEnumerator coroutine;
void Start()
{
    coroutine = SpawnClone(5.0f);
    StartCoroutine(coroutine); //Trigger SpawnClone coroutine and pass in the delay of 5 seconds
    print("Triggered Coroutine SpawnClone");
}

private IEnumerator SpawnClone(float delay)
{
    print("Coroutine tick");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    print("Coroutine logic stared: " + Time.time + " seconds");

    Vector3 originalPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5f, 5f), Random.Range(-2, 2), 100);
    Rigidbody clone;
    clone = Instantiate(original, originalPosition, transform.rotation);
    clone.velocity = rb.velocity * speed;   

    print("Coroutine ended: " + Time.time + " seconds");     
}
```

Comment: The documentation of invoke suggests to use coroutines instead https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

Comment: And if you really want to use invoke (which I really do not recommend), at least use NameOf(YourFunction) instead of passing a string